# clarify pytorch tensor as reference vs value

Tags: pytorch, pass-by-reference

Why does the top code `a = mat[0,0]; a = torch.tensor([99])` not change `mat` but the bottom code `row = mat[0,:]; row[0] = torch.tensor([99])` does?

```
>>> mat = torch.ones(2,3); print(mat)
tensor([[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]])
>>> a = mat[0,0]
>>> a = torch.tensor([99]); print(mat)
tensor([[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]])
>>> row = mat[0,:]
>>> row[0] = torch.tensor([99]); print(mat)
tensor([[99.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `a = torch.tensor([99])`, you change the reference of the `a` variable from the `mat` tensor to the new `torch.tensor([99])`. The assignment here is changing what the variable `a` means.

When you run `row[0] = torch.tensor([99])`, the `row` reference stays the same, but the specific item `row[0]` is changed. Because `row` shares memory with `mat`, `mat` is changed as well. The assignment here is *not* changing the variable `row`, but is changing a specific element of `row`.

You can compare the two assignments more directly.

```py
mat = torch.ones(2,3)
row = mat[0,:]
row[0] = torch.tensor([99]) # here we change element `0` of `row`
print(mat) # mat is changed

mat = torch.ones(2,3)
row = mat[0,:]
row = torch.tensor([99]) # here we change the variable `row` without changing specific elements
print(mat) # mat is unchanged
```